# Getting the result to textfield

Tags: php

I have two tables that i can apply changes to. But i need to echo the changes made based on a certain criteria. Now for the first table, any change made is echoed, however i'm not sure on how to echo the changes if they are made to the second table (the else).

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['ID'])) {
        $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM Employees";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $tempname = $row['Field'];

            // Changes Function
            $sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE ID='".$_GET["id"]."' AND (".$row['Field']." NOT LIKE '".$_POST[$tempname]."')";
            $result3 = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCheck);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result3) > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row3 = mysqli_fetch_array($result3)) {
                    $sql3 = "INSERT INTO `Changes` (`Table`, `ID`, `Attribute`, `DateChanged`, `HRUser`, `OldValue`, `NewValue`) VALUES ('Employees', '".$_GET["id"]."', '".$row["Field"]."', '".date("d/m/Y h:i:sa")."', '$login_session', '$row3[$tempname]', '$_POST[$tempname]')";
                    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql3) === TRUE) {
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql3 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
                    }
                }
            }
            //End Changes Function


             $sql2 = "UPDATE Employees SET ".$row['Field']."= '$_POST[$tempname]' WHERE ID='".$_GET["id"]."'";
            $result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
            if (mysqli_query($con,$sql2) === TRUE) {
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql2 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
                echo '<script>swal("Error", "Something went wrong '.mysqli_error($con).'", "error");</script>';
            }

        }




        echo '<script>swal("Success", "Changes have been saved", "success");</script>';
    } 
    //End If POST Submit True
    else
    {

        $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM Candidates";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $tempname = $row['Field'];


            // Changes Function
            $sqlCheck = "SELECT * FROM Candidates WHERE ID='".$_GET["cid"]."' AND (".$row['Field']." NOT LIKE '%".$_POST[$tempname]."%')";
            $result4 = mysqli_query($con,$sqlCheck);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result4) > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row4 = mysqli_fetch_array($result4)) {
                    $sql4 = "INSERT INTO `Changes` (`Table`, `ID`, `Attribute`, `DateChanged`, `HRUser`, `OldValue`, `NewValue`) VALUES ('Candidates', '".$_GET["cid"]."', '".$row["Field"]."', '".date("d/m/Y h:i:sa")."', '$login_session', '$row4[$tempname]', '$_POST[$tempname]')";
                    if (mysqli_query($con,$sql4) === TRUE) {
                    } else {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql4 . "<br>" . mysqli_error($con);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you format the code in proper manner?

Comment: @PratikSoni i'm sorry what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Use `mysqli_affected_rows()`.

> `mysqli_affected_rows` returns the number of affected rows in a previous MySQL operation

So you can judge if change has been made from previous data or not.

[mysqli_affected_rows php.net reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php)

Comment: dear how and where to use it , i just started learning php.. And how this function can differentiate between the 2 tables?

Comment: You can use it after delete , alter, update etc. statements. Just after execution of any sql statement.